# How to get the system time and then perform an action in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time, action

I am building an app and need to check the system time to match an specific date and then perform certain action.
When user starts the app the index page is run and then the rest of the pages on the app. But I need, when a certain lapse of time elapses let's say, three months, when the user starts the app instead of sowing the index page it shows another one.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: Use `Date()` to get the system time. Save it in `localStorage` the first time they run the application. On future executions, get the localStorage value, compare it to the current time. If 3 months have elapsed, redirect to the other page.

Comment: Of course, the user can defeat this by clearing local storage. A better solution would be to require the user to login to a server application. The server can save the first time in a database, and redirect them when they login 3 months later.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't place any attempt to get it to work on my own. The problem is that I am completely new to javascript and I have always learned what I know by reading and analyzing some other people questions solved before. But in this particular case I couldn't find a any similar done before.

Comment: It's been useful your advice to use Date() and localStorage. Let me try it out and then return with my own code (if I get stuck).

Comment: It is true that the user may clear cache and reset the time stored on localStorage but it will work for me as I think a few little users really know how to do that on an Android device. ¿Or am I completely mistaken on this?

Comment: You will need to store some "last visited" on your server to obtain your objective.  Please put the actual code you have tried and how we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: On Chrome for Android, it's not trivial to erase stored data, but it is certainly possible. There is also Firefox Focus which erases all site data whenever the app is closed. Then there is DuckDuckGo which is "in between": it doesn't always erase all data but it has a big 'Burn' button to do it easily. The only way to make sure is to store the data on the server, and make users login so that their session is never anonymous.